# Java Spring Boot. Cron issue. Variable is not instantiated

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

My Spring Boot app doesn't work properly. The main idea is that user chooses the city he wants to know the temperature in. The temperature value is saved to the txt file with the city name as a file name. And then I want to schedule Cron, so, every hour new temperature value for the same city will be saved to the same file. At the moment everything works fine except CronManager class. I don't understand how to pass the city name to it. Here's the part of my code below:

**ApplicationLoader**

```
package com.boris2barak.samplemvc.app;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication

public class ApplicationLoader extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApplicationLoader.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationLoader.class, args);
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.boris2barak.samplemvc.app;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class myFirstController {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "hello";
}

@RequestMapping("/temperature")
public String whatIsTheTemperature(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "city", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String city) throws IOException {
    model.addAttribute("city", city);
    WeatherApp data = new WeatherApp();
    return data.getTemperatureForCity(city);
}
}
```

**WeatherApp**

```
package com.boris2barak.samplemvc.app;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.io.*;

public class WeatherApp {

public String getTemperatureForCity(String city) throws IOException {
    String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&APPID=9fff4e627587b84fca1ed835321da768";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String json = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, String.class);
    WeatherData weatherData = new Gson().fromJson(json, WeatherData.class);

    ////......... (here i have the code to get the other data like coordinates of the city, humidity, etc which is not relevant to my problem)

    String theTemperature = weatherData.getTemperature();
    FileManager myFile = new FileManager();
    myFile.saveTheFile(theTemperature, city);
    return theTemperature;
}
}
```

**FileManager**

```
package com.boris2barak.samplemvc.app;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import static org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream;

public class FileManager {

public void saveTheFile(String theTemperature, String cityName) throws IOException {
    InputStream streamIn = toInputStream(theTemperature, "UTF-8");
    OutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(cityName + ".txt", true);
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(streamIn, streamOut);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(streamIn);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(streamOut);
    }

}
}
```

**CronManager**

```
package com.boris2barak.samplemvc.app;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CronManager {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * ? * *")
public void cronTask() throws IOException {

WeatherApp data = new WeatherApp();
data.getTemperatureForCity(city <<<< how to instantiate this??);


}
}
```

I'm already 2 days trying to solve this problem. Many thanks for your help!

**The problem is solved. Here's the answer:**https://stackoverflow.com/a/45287683/8258820

Comment: Do you have cities list?

Comment: No, I don't as it could be any city the user wants. At the moment I use ARC to imitate user's request. For example: http://localhost:8080/temperature?city=Paris.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class CronManager {
private Set<String> cities = new HashSet();// or CopyOnWriteArraySet/ConcurrentSkipListSet

public void addCity(String cityName){
     cities.add(cityName);
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * ? * *")
public void cronTask() throws IOException {

        //iterate cities and execute logic in parallel no not block 
        WeatherApp data = new WeatherApp();
        data.getTemperatureForCity(city <<<< how to instantiate this??);
}
}
```

Inject CronManager , as it's a component , into service/controller and add new city into CronManager.cities, when the new city is added. If you need to stop writing city temperature just remove it from the set of city. Better create a new compoment CityHolder and keep cities into one , in this case, you need inject it into cronManager and service/controller but service/controller will not have dependency on cron manager. 
As you have one cron for all files , probably it's better to execute this code parallel by some thread executors or with @Async service / method.

Also you can use spring events. In conroller/service use send custom event AddNewCity and in CronManager add listener for this event and put city from event source into cities set.

---

```
@Controller
public class myFirstController {
    @Autowired
    private CronManager cron;

    @RequestMapping("/temperature")
    public String whatIsTheTemperature(Model model, 
       @RequestParam(value = "city",required = false,defaultValue = "World") String city) 
          throws IOException {
        model.addAttribute("city", city);
        WeatherApp data = new WeatherApp();
        myCron.addCity(city);
        return data.getTemperatureForCity(city);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your idea is very nice! I have put everything to CronManager class like you did it.  Now the city is added to HashEet, cronTask is executed, but it thinks that HashSet is empty. So, in the end I don't get few temperature values for one city.

Comment: I did it like this and I see that it never enters the loop: https://pastebin.com/whunG8r5

Comment: I add via Controller class: https://pastebin.com/XeevV4Hn As you see I have added if statement before the loop inside of CronTask. So, I always else condition is executed. You may delete "data = null;" as it doesn't affect the situation.

Comment: Yes, it works now! Many thanks! Sorry maybe I was not enough attentive yesterday night :-) As I thought that there were no difference between using Autowired and creating new CronManager when method is called. Sorry, I'm learning Java programming on my own just for 2 months that's why my question could look stupid.. As I understand Autowired annotation gives us the possibility to create a new CronManager ? So, at the moment CronManager is created on the start of applications and just waiting for the city to be instantiated... Something like that, right?

Comment: In your case CronManager it's singleton, you inject this instance into controller by autowired  , when you use new CronManager() - you create instance that is not connected to spring context and every call create new separate instance ,  - in this case as it's spring bean you don't apply @Scheduled for this.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your explanation. I have already voted and added a link to your answer as the solution to my post.